# Difference between Fast Map and traditional Map

Tags: java, performance, collections, dictionary

I want to know what is the difference between a standard implementation of java.util.Map interface and some other map implementations which are called Fast Map. And, can you please introduce me some fast map implementations to use?

Best

Answer (score 3):

A general map implementation is something like HashMap. A Fast Map is designed to optimize for reading, but is usually much more expensive to modify. I found this with a quick google search I've never tried it, but it looks pretty good. [Link](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastMap.html)
Also, [here](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) is the Apache collections page, which has stuff like FastLists and other cool collections.